# How do I trigger a recalculation in a Vue app?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm working on a project with Vue and VueX. In my component, I have a calculated method that looks like this:

```
...mapState([
  'watches',
]),

isWatched() {
  console.log('check watch');
  if (!this.watches) return false;
  console.log('iw', this.watches[this.event.id]);
  return this.watches[this.event.id] === true;
},
```

And in my store, I have the following:

```
addWatch(state, event) {
  console.log('add', state.watches);
  state.watches = {
    ...state.watches,
    [event]: true,
  };
  console.log('add2', state.watches);
},
```

However, this doesn't trigger a recalculation. What's going on?

Comment: From where you are doing `commit` the `addWatch` mutation?

Comment: Do you define your initial state with `watches` set to an empty object? If it is initially set, I would expect `state.watches` to be marked as modified, which would trigger a recalculation. Otherwise `state.watches` is likely not reactive, which is a problem since you are also replacing the object that is stored in that key.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `return this.watches[this.event.id] === true;`

to

`return this.$store.commit("addWatch", this.event.id)`;

Comment: This changes what it's doing.

Comment: it will trigger the `addWatch` mutation & `[event]: true` should be true. I guess you are wanting this?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shown is correct, so the problem must be elsewhere.

I assume by 'calculated method' you mean computed property.
Computed properties do not watch their dependencies deeply, but you are updating the store immutably, so that is not the problem.

Here is a bit of sample code to give you the full picture.
Add event numbers until you hit '2', and the `isWatched` property becomes true.

```js
Vue.use(Vuex);
const mapState = Vuex.mapState;

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    watches: {}
  },
  mutations: {
    addWatch(state, event) {
      state.watches = { ...state.watches, [event]: true };
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  data: {
    numberInput: 0,
    event: { id: 2 }
  },
  methods: {
    addNumber(numberInput) {
      this.$store.commit("addWatch", Number(numberInput));
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["watches"]),
    isWatched() {
      if (!this.watches) return false;
      return this.watches[this.event.id] === true;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.1.0/vuex.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>Watches: {{ watches }}</div>
  <div>isWatched: {{ isWatched }}</div>
  <br>
  <input v-model="numberInput" type="number" />
  <button @click="addNumber(numberInput)">
   Add new event
  </button>
</div>
```